# ObservableCollection in the service layer of the WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, observablecollection, service-layer

Examples of WPF MVVM apps I've seen on the Internet consider VM a layer which interacts with a service layer which either uses "old" events from an external library, or interacts with web using HTTP or whatever. But what if I build all M, V, VM, service and other parts myself? How to properly build interaction between the service layer and the viewmodel layer? Can I just put `ObservableCollection<OrderModel>` into the service and return it as is from the viewmodel for the view, or is it considered a bad approach and there're better alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this - of course you can.  The primary reason to do such a thing would be to reduce duplication across multiple WPF applications.

However, a challenge you might have in some scenarios, depending on your service layer/data layer implementation, is long-running services that in turn use database connections.  ObservableCollections are enticing from the point of view of having the service layer automatically synchronising changes made by an application to a data store; however it gets complicated when you want to communicate changes that originate from the data itself (i.e. in response to some other process that creates/modifies data).

The service layer can't really replace the instance (i.e. in the case of large-scale changes), since it is no longer the sole owner of the reference - but even if it could, replacing the instance would pretty much break any binding the UI has to the collection.

So you stick to trying to keep the one instance up to date.  If your services are bound to a database, then unless you code-up some form of long-running monitoring process within your service, the only simple way to keep an ObservableCollection up to date after it's been dished out would be to hold database connections/contexts (in the case of Linq to Sql or EF) open - because otherwise related objects etc are not going to be able to retrievable (unless you force all objects to be read in one go - which is not scalable).

Okay, so it's possible to write some form of management layer which can manage the connections for you - but in addition to the inevitable polling, or perhaps SQL Server notifications that you might use, I believe the code might get quite complicated.

That said, it really does depend - that particular issue is one to look out for, but it might be that you have an architecture and environment in which such things simply don't matter.

My advice, if you want to try it - go ahead.  For me?  I've thought about it - and beyond adding INotifyPropertyChanged to some domain models, I stick to the idea that an application has it's own VM.  Multiple applications might share the same VM - but that won't be internal to the service layer itself.

A service layer provides access to data and business logic in a typically one-shot way.  Classes in the VM pattern are intended to have a much longer lifespan - and trying to code a long-running service layer is notoriously very hard to do - especially if you want it to try and solve all the problems that all future applications might present.  Inevitably you will end up coding services or VM types within the service layer for a single application only - in which case it might as well have gone in that App's codebase.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to use an ObservableCollection only from the point at which the "observable" aspect is relevant, which is generally the VM exposing something to the V. Further down the stack (i.e. the M) I'd be tempted to stick with more generic things like lists and collections (unless you specifically need for things to be otherwise). Its easy enough for the VM to create an ObservableCollection based on any old IEnumerable in any case.

A reasonable question though, especially as ObservableCollection's placement in the System.Collections namespace would seem to suggest that Microsoft don't particularly think of this as a specialized class (and certainly not wpf-specific).

Comment: The problem with sticking to "traditional" lists and enumerables, is that I still need to update the view via the viewmodel when something is added to the list; so viewmodel needs to be notified about a new item by the service. If I add events, it'll look like a bad (and probably buggy) implementation of observable collection...

Comment: @Athari I can see where you're coming from - it certainly makes no sense for you to implement your own ObservableCollection. Looking further down the stack, how will the service know that things have changed?

Comment: @Athari - That is exactly what I do. When I add a new item programmatically (i.e. not using the DataGrid new line, but adding an entity), I have an OnEntityAdded event that I throw from the Create method in my Repository: **OnEntityAdded(new ModelEntityAddedEventArgs(entity))**. As you can see, the entity is passed in the event arguments. My service layer subscribes to this event.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that for a number of reasons.  They're documented here: [Common mistakes with an observable collection](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection)

The author goes through several mistakes people make with them, including using them in the service layer.

Comment: The article says in the "Using it in the model" section that using OC in models is bad, but I've seen many examples when models are given as is into the view, without any conversion. One of the recommendations was: "If a model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, use it; otherwise, convert it". So using observable collections in models isn't considered a bad practice by everybody... Anyway, the question is: what is the alternative way, right way?

Comment: I believe the alternative way (right way) is to use IEnumerable. Like @PeteH suggested, try to only use OC as far up as possible, aka in your ViewModel. And write a CollectionViewModel class that exposes the ObservableCollection of ViewModels as a property, with subscriptions to OnCollectionChanged, etc.

Comment: original link is invalid now. Use this one: http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection.html