# Model List<T> and ViewModel ObservableCollection<T> Duplicate Data?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm, observablecollection

What is the best practice for having a `List<T>` in the business layer that needs to be displayed on a UI? I currently use databinding with an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the viewmodel that duplicates the data of the `List<T>`. The obvious problem of this is when the `List<T>` is modified in the business layer the `ObservableCollection<T>` needs to be recreated so the changes of the `List<T>` are reflected in the UI. This can't be the best way.

I also will not accept using an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the business layer as an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: who and when and how is modifying your `List<T>` in the model?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the general problem where the List could be modified programmatically and or through the UI without duplicating data.

Comment: "programatically" from where? from the Model itself? from the VM? please post more details.

Comment: Assume the List could be modified from the viewmodel or model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you insist on having `List<T>` and separate events notifying about list modification, then duplication is the only sensible way.

   1. If you have `ListChanged` event with no details on what was actually changed, you can avoid duplication and just wrap the list in a proxy collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface which will fire appropriate `CollectionChanged` events in `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` mode.
   2. If you have granular `ItemChanged`, `ItemAdded` etc. events, then you're effectively duplicating `ObservableCollection<T>` functionality. In this case, you can wrap your application in a proxy collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, but which understands your architecture and translates events into appropriate `NotifyCollectionChangedAction`.
2. Having `ObservableCollection<T>` in business layer isn't a bad idea at all. It is a specialized collection which provides common interface to notify about item changes, not some class designed specifically for WinForms or WPF or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I've had a preconceived notion that using an ObservableCollection is bad unless dealing directly with a UI. Are there any obvious pitfalls extensibility-wise when using an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Rydel See the question [ObservableCollection in the service layer of the WPF MVVM application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839097/observablecollection-in-the-service-layer-of-the-wpf-mvvm-application), it has high-quality answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, but if you want to use it in a way that you can hold on your implementation the collection in case implementing a class of your own also holding an implementation of IEnumerable will do a lot of the work for you a for instance is what follows, this is the base class i use for holding all the collections that will be updated, on this implementation there is also an ordering consideration in the variable _ordering:

```
public abstract class BaseINotifyCollectionChanged<T, K> : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<T>
{
    Func<T, K> _ordering;
    bool _ascending;

    public BaseINotifyCollectionChanged()
    {
    }

    public BaseINotifyCollectionChanged(Func<T, K> ordering, bool ascending = true)
    {
        _ordering = ordering;
        _ascending = ascending;
        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected abstract IList<T> GetCollection();

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
    public void RaiseCollectionChanged()
    {
        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _ordering == null ? GetCollection().GetEnumerator() : _ascending ? GetCollection().OrderBy<T, K>(_ordering).GetEnumerator() :
                                                                                  GetCollection().OrderByDescending<T, K>(_ordering).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _ordering == null ? GetCollection().GetEnumerator() : _ascending ? GetCollection().OrderBy<T, K>(_ordering).GetEnumerator() :
                                                                                  GetCollection().OrderByDescending<T, K>(_ordering).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
}
```

When you have this implementation you can use as you wish and through out all the collections you need on your app, working on some **dry** for yourself here is one example of the use you can give to this abstract class:

```
public class Categories : BaseINotifyCollectionChanged<Category, string>
{
    long _onCategoryRoot;
    public void SetOnCategoryRoot(long categoryId)
    {
        _onCategoryRoot = categoryId;
        RaiseCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected override IList<Category> GetCollection()
    {
        Category category = new Category();
        return _onRoot ? category.GetRootCategories() : category.GetSubCategoriesOnRoot(_onCategoryRoot);
    }
}
```

When you set a **_onCategoryRoot** in the class the collection you will be displaying will be updated via the **RaiseCollectionChanged()** method, so you need to add in your viewmodel a property with the class **Categories** and set the binding in the XAML.